# How to include a cpp file for all the function and classes but ignore the main function?

Tags: python, c++

I used to use python and now I'm shifting to c++ for efficiency. I used to have the habit to test the library file with a main function, just to make sure all the functions and classes are working fine. And

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

works really well even if I need to import the file for other codes.

However, I am not sure how can I do the same for c++. I know I can comment out main function in the library file before I want to include that file. But I would really like to know is there any equivalent method in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you shouldn't do it the python way but write a small test program to test your library. To design it the python way is not common in C++ and you will not make many new friends doing it.

But if you **really** want to do that, you can define main as a weak symbol.

```
int __attribute__((weak)) main() {
      [your code]
}
```

The linker will override any weak symbol if it finds a non-weak symbol. That trick is for example used by lex/flex to give you a generic main if you don't write your own.

As StoryTeller mentioned it is not in the standard and not available on all platforms. Especially not on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I need to pick up more mindsets and common practice with C++ community